# Ubuntu stuck at please remove installation medium then press enter in Virtualbox

Tags: boot, system-installation, keyboard, virtualbox, 21.10

When I was installing Ubuntu 21.10 in Virtualbox, 'please remove installation medium then press enter' command appeared so I just pressed enter since the iso is already removed. Nothing happened on the screen. Ive tried doing this multiple times but never managed to pass through this area. How do I get to the next steps?

Comment: Yep. That is exactly what you should do. That's how Ubuntu rolls.

Comment: How much RAM did you allocate? How much Video RAM? How long are you waiting at 'black screen' before giving up? Does the Virtualbox disk indicator show activity? Did you follow the tutorial EXACTLY or did you make any changes at all? Did you verify the install .iso image? Did you enable virtualization in your BIOS?

Answer (score 1):

Once the .iso is removed, reboot the VM. It should boot into the installed instance of Ubuntu.

Pressing Enter is merely supposed to trigger a reboot.

Comment: I think you actually have to manually reboot the VM from the power menu.

Comment: I have tried doing that and Virtualbox woould reboot and show a black screen

Comment: @Anonymous7641 Did you install GRUB to the VM? Presumably, you did, as it is part of the Ubuntu installation.

Comment: I just followed this guide: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-run-ubuntu-desktop-on-a-virtual-machine-using-virtualbox

Comment: Very sorry for not mentioning the steps that I have taken to solve it myself. Its my 1st time here.

Comment: Please [edit your Question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1393449/edit) above to include the additional important details,

Comment: @user535733 Be nice to new users.

Comment: @heynnema Mea culpa. Thanks for pointing it out.