# Please remove the installation medium, then press ENTER - finishing Ubuntu installation in VirtualBox

Tags: boot, system-installation, virtualbox, 23.04

I've just installed Ubuntu 23.04 in VirtualBox. Now the program says:

> Please remove the installation medium, then press ENTER:

(please see the first screenshot.)

I've seen [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/915814/please-remove-the-installation-medium-then-press-enter?newreg=cda83cf189614ca4ad560261c0a44e6d) post, [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1393446/ubuntu-stuck-at-please-remove-installation-medium-then-press-enter-in-virtualbox) post and many others addressing exactly the same question, however, none of them have helped.

How am I supposed to remove the installation medium? What exactly does this mean? Also, where do I press 'Enter'? Presumably inside the VirtualBox?

[One website](https://turbofuture.com/computers/How-to-Install-Ubuntu-on-VirtualBox) I came across says:

> While the new operating system is rebooting, there will be a message saying "Please remove installation media and close the tray (if any) then press "ENTER". To do this, click "Devices" at the top of the window and hover over "CD/DVD devices". You should see a device with Ubuntu in the name with a checkmark next to it. Click this device to remove the checkmark, then press Enter.

When I try removing the checkmark (by clicking on it), the following message pops up (please see screenshot 2).

What should I do? Please explain as though you were teaching a monkey.
I do apologise if this post is far too basic for this SE; I hope it helps beginners like myself!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, I simply selected: Devices > Optical Drives, then selected 'ubuntu-23.04-desktop-amd64.iso' and clicked 'Remove disk from virtual drive' (as shown in the screenshot). It worked. [image]

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark next to it and turn it green. This will help others.

Comment: @user68186 ok, I'll do it tomorrow (when the site allows me to :) )